# Calling multiple superclass constructors

Tags: java, constructor, superclass, super

please read the following code. I have kept it very simple to understand. It does not contain any error...

```
class A {
    private int a;
    private int b;

    A() {
        System.out.println("a and b: " + a + " " + b);
    }

    A(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

class B extends A{
    B(int a, int b) {
        super(a,b);
        super(); // error, "Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor"
    }
}


public class Construct {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B(3,4);
    }
}
```

I need to know that how can i call the no-args constructor of superclass A, in this situation? So that i can display the values of a and b. please explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call two super-class constructors from the sub-class constructor. Your alternative is to call the parameter-less constructor of the super class A from the other constructor of the super class.

```
A(int a, int b) {
    this ();
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

class B extends A{
    B(int a, int b) {
        super(a,b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast... but can you please explain it by writing code? please its a request. i learnt a lot of difficult things today.

Comment: @PirateX Note that at the time of calling `this()` a and b won't be initialized.

Comment: i know how to use this(), but as you know this() must be the first statement. and i am initializing values after that.

Comment: hi user2336315 thanks for replying, can you tell me any alternative?

Comment: @PirateX If you want to call some initialization logic of class A from an arbitrary location in class B constructor, you can move that logic to a regular method of class A, which doesn't have the restrictions that constructor calls have.

Comment: @Eran thanx again for replying... yes i can use a method for that.(say showvalues() or something like that) but i just want to know if there is a way to call that default constructor after initializaton of a and b. please reply.

Answer (score 0):

You should re-think you object oriented design. Constructurs with less arguments call constructors with more arguments, not the other way round. So you'll do this:

```
class A {
    private int a;
    private int b;

    A() {
        this(0, 0);  // default constructor: initialize with some useful default values
    }

    A(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        System.out.println("a and b: " + this.a + " " + this.b);
    }
}

class B extends A{
    B(int a, int b) {
        super(a,b);
    }
}


public class Construct {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B(3,4);
    }
}
```